# mongodb querying next N documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

In Mongodb, is it possible to query the next N documents?

i.e

```
collection.find({ 'temperature': 1.0 }).sort("datetime", 1).next({ [ 'temperature': 1.1, 'temperature': 1.2 ] }, 2)
```

query would return results only after document where temperature 1.0 next one is 1.1 and after the next temperature is 1.2? (they follow the order)